# Does setuptools' find_packages require __init__.py files or not to recognize packages

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

Does setuptools' `find_packages` still require that packages have an `__init__.py` file inside?

The [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#basic-use) says

> Packages are only recognized if they include an `__init__.py` file.

But I read that `__init__.py` files are not required anymore to mark a directory as a python package.

Answer (score 7):

***Update***

Looking back, the original answer is misguided.

*Package initializers* (the `__init__.py` files) should always be there. Because of some implementation details, it is true that it might work without, but it is not something that was strictly intended and not something that should be relied on.

Some details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62992832
- https://discuss.python.org/t/mixing-namespace-and-non-namespace-packages-bad-practice/7536/6
- https://discuss.python.org/t/init-py-pep-420-and-iter-modules-confusion/9642
- [*PEP 420*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420)

---

***Original answer***

In recent version of Python the *package initializers* (the `__init__.py` files) are not strictly necessary, meaning that such packages can be imported and so on.

But *setuptools* is not Python, so to say. And in particular `find_packages` still bases its lookup on the presence of such files. On the other hand, *setuptools* also offers the alternative [`find_namespace_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages) function, that is able to find packages that do not contain a package initializer.

Comment: I would like to add the following directly from [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification): "A namespace package is not fundamentally different from a regular package. It is just a different way of creating packages. Once a namespace package is created, there is no functional difference between it and a regular package."

Comment: And also from [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#discussion): "There is no intention to remove support of regular packages. If a developer knows that her package will never be a portion of a namespace package, then there is a performance advantage to it being a regular package (with an `__init__.py`). Creation and loading of a regular package can take place immediately when it is located along the path. With namespace packages, all entries in the path must be scanned before the package is created."