# How to install multiple python namespace packages in editable mode

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I created multiple packages according to the PEP420 implicit namespace packaging method. Two of those distribution packages are `dende-github-api` and `dende-gitlab-api`. Each of those distributions contains one module which I want to be accessible unter the `dende.api` namespace. A minimal <s>working</s> example can be found here: https://github.com/dende/example-monorepositry

This is the folder structure of the Repository containing both distributions:

```
example-monorepository
├── dende-github-api
│   ├── dende
│   │   └── api
│   │       ├── github.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── setup.py
├── dende-gitlab-api
│   ├── dende
│   │   └── api
│   │       ├── gitlab.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── setup.py
├── requirements.dev.txt
└── requirements.txt
```

And the `setup.py`'s look like this (only showing for dende-github-api):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='dende-github-api',
    packages=['dende.api'],
    install_requires=[
        'PyGithub'
    ]
)
```

I can install both distributions and use them just fine:

```
$ pip install ./dende-github-api
$ pip install ./dende-gitlab-api
$ python -m dende.api.github
Hi from dende-github-api from /home/c/git/example-monorepositry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dende/api/github.py
$ python -m dende.api.gitlab
Hi from dende-gitlab-api from /home/c/git/example-monorepositry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dende/api/gitlab.py
```

When I install both distributions in editable mode, only one of the installations work:

```
$ pip install -e ./dende-github-api
$ pip install -e ./dende-gitlab-api
python -m dende.api.gitlab                          
Hi from dende-gitlab-api from /home/c/git/example-monorepositry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dende/api/gitlab.py
python -m dende.api.github
/home/c/git/example-monorepositry/venv/bin/python: No module named dende.api.github
```

Somehow the second installation seems to shadow the installation of the older distribution in the overlapping namespace. Is it possible to install overlapping packages like these in editable mode?

Comment: BTW, per [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification): "*Namespace packages cannot contain an \__init__.py.*" Both your `setup.py` don't decalre namespace packages, is it ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your modules are in the regular package `dende.api`, because they both contain an `__init__.py`. So, they are not really in an implicit namespace package. Only one of the two `dende.api`s will be available.

It works when installing them in non-editable mode only by accident, because the files are written into the same directory on disk, but not because of the namespace package mechanism.

You can repair that by removing the `__init__.py`s and thereby making `dende.api` a namespace package or by renaming the two `api`s into distinct packages `github-api` and `gitlab-api`, which then both are in the namespace package `dende`.

A more detailed explanation of the namespace package mechanisms for a somehow related problem (why it makes only little sense to have namespace packages inside regular ones) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62992832

Comment: how is that "by accident" - can't this also be intent?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. Editable install works by creating a file `<package_name>.egg-link` in `site-packages/` pointed back to the source directory. You may have only 1 (one) such link so you can install only one package named `<package_name>` (even if it's a namespace package) in develop/editable mode.

See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html

Comment: For me it creates egg-links with the names of the [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package), not with the name of the contained package: it creates `dende-github-api.egg-link` and `dende-gitlab-api.egg-link` for me