# How does a blank __init__.py change the behavior of import in python?

Tags: python, import, package, python-import, python-packaging

I'm seeing many examples online that seem to indicate mere inclusion of a **blank** `__init__.py` file in a folder turns from a namespace package into a package. I'd like to figure out what this actually means. Consider the following example:

```
root
└───a
        b.py
        __init__.py
```

The python files contain no code, as this is only for demonstration purposes. Whether I include the **blank** `__init__.py` file or not, there is no difference in the following:

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 18 2021, 14:42:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
>>> import a
>>> a.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'b'
>>> b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>>> from a import b
>>> b
<module 'a.b' from 'C:\\Users\\user_id\\desktop\\temp\\packages_question\\a\\b.py'>
```

I understand that including a `from . import b` statement inside a_*init*_.py will change things, but that's not what this question is about. I'm more interested in the role of a **blank** `__init__.py`. How does the **blank** `__init__.py` change the behavior of `import` in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Kind of, although the question is not specifically about *blank* __init__.py files. There is some hint that these are not required anymore in newer python versions but I still would like to know how they change pythons behavior when they are included as blank files...

Comment: Try reading [this subparagraph](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules), it seems to me it's very related to your problem

Comment: That's still not about blank __init__.py files!

Comment: This might clarify things: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62992832